# Como parar um loop utilizando a entrada fornecida pelo usuário?

Tags: python, algoritmo, loop, lista, dicionário

Estou escrevendo um programa que recebe entradas e cria um dicionário a partir delas. Preciso que o laço que utilizo para inserir as entradas no dicionário seja quebrado quando a entrada for "9999", mas não está funcionando. Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira: dic = dict()

```
dic = dict()
gabarito = raw_input()
um = 1
zero = 0
while zero < um:
    entrada = raw_input()
    lista = entrada.split()
    dic[lista[1]] = lista[0]
    if entrada == 9999: 
        break
print dic
```

O que está errado? Como proceder?

Comment: onde esta declarada a variável `dic`?

Comment: coloque o restante do código do seu programa.

Comment: Primeira linha adicionada.

Comment: o loop vai continuar enquanto o usuário informa valores diferentes de 9999, isso deve ser um laço infinito, vc não precisa das variáveis `zero` e `um`, basta colocar `while(true)` ou `while(1)` que são loops infinitos, e sair do loop com o break.

Comment: Mas qual seria a condição para sair do loop?

Comment: Quando  entrada for igual a 9999.

Comment: qual erro recebes?

Comment: Não funciona. Recebo o erro: dic[lista[1]] = lista[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Vc deve especificar a chave correta para o seu dicionario, para determinar o valor de acordo com a posição da chave.

Comment: Não entendi. O programa não deveria entender já que estou utilizando a entrada como condição para o break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das primeiras coisas a considerar é fazer a adição do par à variável `dic` somente depois do `break`, afinal, se vai usar o 9999 como saída, não é para o `9999` entrar no dicionário, principalmente pelo fato do `split` não dividir o `9999` em duas partes.

Outra coisa é que `entrada` tem que ser comparado com `'9999'` em vez de `9999`, por estar entrando como *string*:

```
dic = dict()
gabarito = raw_input()
um = 1
zero = 0
while zero < um:
    entrada = raw_input()
    lista = entrada.split()
    if entrada == '9999': 
        break
    dic[lista[1]] = lista[0]
print dic
```

Obviamente que isto serve apenas como um exercício, pois o ideal seria proteger o código sanitizando as entradas, em vez de deixar dar o erro.

Um exemplo simples de como proteger a entrada (e otimizando o `while`):

```
dic = dict()
gabarito = raw_input()
while True:
    entrada = raw_input()
    lista = entrada.split()
    if entrada == '9999': 
        break
    elif len(lista) < 2:
        print 'forneca dois valores, ou 9999 para sair'
    dic[lista[1]] = lista[0]
print dic
```